# Docker, no IPAddress in docker inspect

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I m using the following dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER xxx xxx<xx@xx.com>


# SSH
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:xxxxxxx' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]



# NodeJS Apache2
RUN apt-get update &&\
        apt-get -y upgrade &&\
        apt-get -y install nodejs nodejs-legacy nodejs-dev npm git curl apache2
```

I have followed :https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/#run-a-test_sshd-container
but it seems that I dont have an IPAddress.

What am I doing wrong, or what I haven't done ?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that you don't have an IP address for your container, not for the boot2docker VM.  What exactly is the output of `docker inspect <YOUR_CONTAINER>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to run `boot2docker ip` and use that